# SQL get value from multiple tables and then order it

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do a MySQL query. I have 4 tables : A, B, C, D.

I want to get common value : "wins" from all 4 tables WHERE "account" = 1 and then order it by  most "wins". And all ordered "wins" LIMIT to 3 .

I will be really glad, if u help me.

I tried something like this :

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (
(SELECT wins FROM 'A')
UNION ALL
(SELECT wins FROM 'B')
UNION ALL
(SELECT wins FROM 'C')
UNION ALL
(SELECT wins FROM 'D')
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM 'A'
WHERE
    account=1) 
) AS o
ORDER BY wins DESC
```

but this is really wrong.

Comment: Did you tried something??

Comment: Have you tried a UNION?

Comment: By the sounds of things, you have your database setup incorrectly. For what purpose do you have the same information spread to four different tables?

Comment: It has reason for same name in different tables.

Comment: show your table structures and some sample data and expected output.  and prefereably - what you have already tried that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to know the table from which you get the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT wins, 'Table A' AS DataTable
        FROM TableA
        WHERE account = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT wins, 'Table B' 
        FROM TableB
        WHERE account = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT wins, 'Table C' 
        FROM TableC
        WHERE account = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT wins, 'Table D' 
        FROM TableD
        WHERE account = 1) AS X
ORDER BY wins
LIMIT 3
```

If that isn't important and you only need the highest different `wins`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT wins
        FROM TableA
        WHERE account = 1
        UNION
        SELECT wins
        FROM TableB
        WHERE account = 1
        UNION
        SELECT wins
        FROM TableC
        WHERE account = 1
        UNION
        SELECT wins
        FROM TableD
        WHERE account = 1) AS X
ORDER BY wins DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT o.* FROM `A`
JOIN `B`
JOIN `C`
JOIN `D` 
ON `D`.`account`=`A`.`account` 
AND `C`.`account`=`A`.`account` 
AND `B`.`account`=`A`.`account` 
AND `A`.`account`='1'
ORDER BY `A`.`wins`